# Working with LFTP, find and -exec option throws error

Tags: linux, unix, find, lftp

What is wrong with the following lftp command? There files on server. I am trying to get their names without any path in it (like `./`) Just file names.

```
lftp -u user,password -e 'find -exec basename {} \; ;bye' ftp.mycompany.com/Courses >/opt/output/downloaded/course_list
```

I get the following error -

```
cd ok, cwd=/Courses
find: invalid option -- 'e'
Usage: find [-d #] dir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows exactly what parameter find must get to start: it's the directory under which it must seek. Actually, that's the only parameter that must be there, all the rest is for your sake.

On the other hand, you don't have to call basename to omit the directories from the output. Using -printf and the appropriate sequences, you can print any piece of the properties of the files found.
man find will help.

Comment: Its an FTP server. Probably different find package. Is there a place where I can see syntax of find? I tried all combinations I found online. None work. I tried this - `lftp -u user,password -e 'find -d .; ;bye' ftp.mycompany.com/Courses >/opt/output/downloaded/course_list`, then it says `find: . - not a number`

Comment: If I give `-e 'find .; ;bye' ` then it works. So, then I added `-e 'find . -exec basename {}\; ;bye'`. Then it takes all space separated tokens as directories. Says -exec accessdenied; basename accessdenied; etc.,

Comment: -d# would probably mean find in directory depth of # levels, you can just forget that here. The most simple way to run find is "find ." which lists the content of the current directory.

Comment: I suggested above forgetting calling basename and use -print. To be precise -printf "%f\n" But I'm afraid your problem is more serious. Looks like you have a simplified find which hardly knows any of what a normal find would.

Comment: same thing..! when I give `-e 'find . -printf "%f\n"; bye'`, it says `find: Access failed: 550 Failed to change directory. (/Courses/-printf)`

Comment: That find is mutilated to be small to fit the firmware.  This won't work. But you can list the files with the paths into your output file/pipe and filter that  to contain only the the names. Just a sed/awk one-liner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36297/discussion-between-user2023507-and-gombai-sandor).